# Firefox float right behaviour

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a simple menu ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myrluk3/JfGVE/193/)). The `float: right` css is not working well in FireFox. I think it should work like in Chrome/IE, the red cube should be inline with the menu item.

Somebody knows why is this? Or how to correct it....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element you are floating should be defined *before* the content that you want to float around it. Move the red boxes to be before the text, and it should work fine.